# Grails unit testing and bootstrap

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I wrote an unit test for a controller.

I have a Bootstrap file which alter the metaclass of domain classes by adding a method `asPublicMap()`. I use this method in the controller to return domain classes as json but only some selected *public* fields.

My unit test failed because of `MissingMethodException` for `asPublicMap()`. As I understood, bootstrap classes are not loaded for unit tests, only for integration tests. That's why I got this error.

My question is : Is there another place to put metaclass manipulation in order to take them into account during unit tests ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply resolved by moving the unit test into an integration test. Bootstrap classes are loaded for integration test, so now it works well.

My concern on that migration was about the `@Mock` annotation, but surprisingly it works also in integration tests. The database isn't used for mocked domain classes.